# lsqr result strongly depends on weights

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I need to solve:

```
argmin||W*FT^-1(Ax)-W*p||
```

using lsqr. p is image, x is k-space matrix, A is a matrix and W is a weighting matrix. In order to pass them to matlab lsqr, I vectorized p, x and W.

This is my code:

```
b=W.*p;
x=lsqr(@(x1,modo)FUNC(x1,W_vector,A,modo),b,tol,maxit);
X_k_lsqr=reshape(x,dim(1),dim(2),dim(3));
X_lsqr=real(ifftn(X_k_lsqr)).*MASK(:,:,:,1);
```

%% Auxiliary function

```
function [result modo]=FUNC(x1,W_vector,A,modo)
    %Computes y=A*x for modo='notransp'
    %Computes y=A'*x for modo='transp'
    switch modo
        case 'notransp'
            res=A*x1;
            R1=reshape(res,norient,dim(1)*dim(2)*dim(3));
            for co=1:norient
                R2(:,:,:,co)=reshape(R1(co,:),dim(1),dim(2),dim(3));
                FR(:,:,:,co)=ifftn(R2(:,:,:,co));
                aux=FR(:,:,:,co);
                R3(co,:)=aux(:).';
            end
            result=W.*R3(:); 
        case 'transp'
            RR1=reshape(x1./(W+eps),norient,dim(1)*dim(2)*dim(3));
            for co=1:norient
                RR2(:,:,:,co)=reshape(RR1(co,:),dim(1),dim(2),dim(3));
                FRR(:,:,:,co)=fftn(RR2(:,:,:,co));
                aux=FRR(:,:,:,co);
                RR3(co,:)=aux(:).'; 
            end
            result=A'*RR3(:); 
    end
end
```

As W appears in both terms of the minimization problem, I would have expected the image I obtain as a result to be almost independent on W values.

The image looks qualitatively the same if I change W, but its values strongly depend on W. I don't know if something is wrong with my code.

Should I actually obtain almost the same values for different W?

Answer (score 2):

A question: Have you checked the flag? Are you sure that you are using the results while the flag is 0?
An argument: I can assume W also as a switch that determines which components of p I want to minimize. If W*(Ax-b) is really equal to 0, then you are right but here we know that there is not an exact solution and it becomes W*(Ax-b) < W*tolerance. So, you are depending the end point of the algorithm on the elements of W together with the tolerance.

Comment: I checked the flag, it is 0 but the result still depends on W. An example: for W, the obtained values are in the range of 1e-2; for 10*W they are in the range of 1e-4

Comment: I wish, I could generate the same issue. I have seen these kind of dependencies where there is only a sub-optimal solution. So, in that situation, the solution depends on the initial guess, the weights and solver tolerances. I'm not sure but your answer implies that this W manipulates the solver precision as I said in the previous answer. So, the solver stops where residue becomes near W*tolerance.

Comment: I added an initial guess and now the result does not depend on W. I still do not obtain the result I hoped but at least this problem seems to be solved. Thank you!